# Find out missing values based on mapping in Pandas

Tags: pandas

I have 2 datasets:

```
df_1.head(4)

region  postal_code
Adrar   1000
Broko   5633
Conan   4288
Cymus   7435


df_2.head(4)

Name     Charges   region    postal_code   Revenue    
Lia        HG       Pintol    4522           345
Joss       PX       Inend     7455           142
Amph       CT                 5633           148
Andrew     UY       Liven     9033           147
```

The second dataset has many missing values in 'region' column... But we can get those missing values using first dataset by matching values of postal_code... For example, in the third row of df_2, 'region' column is missing but by matching it's respective postal_code with df_1, we can find it's region as 'Broko'...  Can someone please suggest on how to code it

Answer (score 0):

You can use [boolean indexing](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) and a [`map`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html):

```
m = df2['region'].isna()
df2.loc[m, 'region'] = (df2.loc[m, 'postal_code']
                           .map(df1.set_index('postal_code')['region'])
                        )
```

Another less efficient approach could be:

```
df2['region'] = (df2['region']
                 .fillna(df2['postal_code']
                         .map(df1.set_index('postal_code')['region']))
                )

# or in place
df2['region'].update(df2['postal_code']
                     .map(df1.set_index('postal_code')['region']))
```

Output:

```
     Name Charges  region  postal_code  Revenue
0     Lia      HG  Pintol         4522      345
1    Joss      PX   Inend         7455      142
2    Amph      CT   Broko         5633      148
3  Andrew      UY   Liven         9033      147
```

Answer (score 0):

**Example**

```
data1 = {'region': {0: 'Adrar', 1: 'Broko', 2: 'Conan', 3: 'Cymus'},
         'postal_code': {0: 1000, 1: 5633, 2: 4288, 3: 7435}}
data2 = {'Name': {0: 'Lia', 1: 'Joss', 2: 'Amph', 3: 'Andrew'},
         'Charges': {0: 'HG', 1: 'PX', 2: 'CT', 3: 'UY'},
         'region': {0: 'Pintol', 1: 'Inend', 2: None, 3: 'Liven'},
         'postal_code': {0: 4522, 1: 7455, 2: 5633, 3: 9033},
         'Revenue': {0: 345, 1: 142, 2: 148, 3: 147}}
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data1)
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data2)
```

**Code**

use `map` and `fillna`

```
mapper = df1.set_index('postal_code')['region']
df2.assign(region=df2['region'].fillna(df2['postal_code'].map(mapper)))
```

result:

```
    Name    Charges region  postal_code Revenue
0   Lia     HG      Pintol  4522        345
1   Joss    PX      Inend   7455        142
2   Amph    CT      Broko   5633        148
3   Andrew  UY      Liven   9033        147
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
mapper = dict(df1.values[:, ::-1])
df2['region'] = df2['region'].combine_first(df2['postal_code'].replace(mapper))
```